# How Does The Aerodynamics Of This Hanging Rotating Wing VAWT Turbine Function?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, aerospace-engineering, aerodynamics

We are examining videos of this very fast rotating "hanging VAWT" shown on Youtube:

https://youtu.be/O2MZsK0mvBk
https://youtu.be/7hVQ_rVNRUI

It say in the text description that "Aerodynamic Lift-Force" is making it turn so quick.

But how it turn **so stable 360 degrees** when it is hanging down from a piece of thread?

Should flow not push it away to the sides or make rotation unstable?

Also what is the sphere on the sides doing? Is it for better weight?

Can somebody explain this aerodynamics behaviour please?

Thank you!

Comment: Should gravity be included in your analysis? What about centre of mass? And balancing…

Comment: Nothing to see here. You can't get much power out of it. If you tried, it would start behaving badly. They are just using a crappy camera. You can't see the fan blades either.